# Displaying fractions in python 3.5

Tags: python-3.x

I am writing a game for kids, for which I am required to display fractions as they are. For example, if I have to write 1 over 2, the kids **will not understand** something like:

> 1/2

but **will understand**:

> ½

Basically, I would like to put fractions in the following format during output. I use  Python 3.5 with IDLE, which is my output window.

Comment: Use replace or something related and then replace with unicode or char code etc

Comment: All right. What if I want to write (x+2) over (x+5), for example, because it so  happen that for 1/2 we have a Unicode character.

Comment: there's not necessarily a way to display fractions in a slanted for like the unicode 1/2. The only way I see this working is just putting it in standard form. I don't see how you'd achieve this

Comment: I see. But that's my problem, because displaying slanted fractions will distract the children from the fact that numerator comes over denominator .They find this slanted fraction notation confusing ( I know this sounds odd, but many of the kids complained that this notation was confusing them, especially when they had to deal with it in applications of BODMAS in a badly written textbook). I would like fractions the way we would write it in latex,for example, where it's amply clear where the numerator and denominator are.

Comment: You could write the divide line straight across eliminating the slant altogether, not sure if that's an option

Comment: That's a good idea, so I will use it for now. Thank you.